# selenium headless chrome java ignore ssl errors

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, ssl-certificate, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium headless chrome testing with java in unix returns empty page source as

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

which was due to accessing the secure http (https) website.

Is there a way to ignore the ssl certificate issue? Please let me know how to ignore it.

Selenium Version 3.7.1..java version 1.8.0.144 chrome driver version 2.33
Chrome Version 62+

I gave a try with options below..but it doesn't seem to work.

```
1. ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
            options.setHeadless(true);DesiredCapabilities capabilities = 
   DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--
                ignore-certificate-errors,--web-security=false,--ssl-
                protocol=any,--ignore-ssl-errors=true"));
   capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

2. DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Am i doing this in a right way? Let me know the trick to make it work

Thanks in advance

Complete Code:

```
WebDriver driver = null;

        try {

            String filePath = "Path to driver";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath);

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
            options.addArguments("test-type");

            String[] switches = {"--ignore-certificate-errors"};

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList(switches));
            capabilities.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

            driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://meta.stackexchange.com");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("PAGE SOURCE : \n" + driver.getPageSource());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
```

Comment: Please show us the code for getpagesource

Comment: System.out.println("PAGE SOURCE : \n" + driver.getPageSource());

Comment: did the page loaded before the driver.getPageSource()? usually if you call driver.getPageSource() before driver.get("yoururl"); above error occurs

Comment: I have placed the getPageSource only after url is loaded..Its working good in Windows machine..this happens only in UNIX headless chrome

Comment: try set the property for chrome driver System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "yourchromedriverlocation");

Comment: Selenium/ChromeDriver version? Please show the entire code block of your trials.

Comment: Updated the complete code..please take a look at

Comment: You haven't mentioned the Selenium/ChromeDriver version.

Comment: Again, you mentioned `java in unix` but your path is `C:\\..\\chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Updated my question..the path was copied from windows machine directly..pls ignore that

Answer (score 0):

Now you can add capabilities in option. please try following:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```